# SQL-Statement to check the role of a user in a moodle course

Tags: php, moodle, roles

can I get the role_ID of a user in a course with a SQL Statemant?

I also want to know what is the role of the user in the course?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT r.id, r.shortname 
        FROM mdl_role_assignments AS ra 
       LEFT JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS ue ON ra.userid = ue.userid 
       LEFT JOIN mdl_role AS r ON ra.roleid = r.id 
       LEFT JOIN mdl_context AS c ON c.id = ra.contextid 
       LEFT JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON e.courseid = c.instanceid AND ue.enrolid = e.id 
       WHERE ue.userid = ? AND e.courseid = ?;
```

Comment: No problem ;) You may validate this solution if you think it´s helped you (the 'check' thing (like a v) on the left of the answer.

Comment: The table user_enrolments should also be prefixed with 'mdl_' like others to reflect the default Moodle prefix.